# Speedup sympy-lamdified and vectorized function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, sympy

I am using sympy to generate some functions for numerical calculations. Therefore I lambdify an expression an vectorize it to use it with numpy arrays. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def numpy_function():
    x, y, z = np.mgrid[0:1:40*1j, 0:1:40*1j, 0:1:40*1j]
    T   = (1 - np.cos(2*np.pi*x))*(1 - np.cos(2*np.pi*y))*np.sin(np.pi*z)*0.1
    return T

def sympy_function():
    x, y, z = sp.Symbol("x"), sp.Symbol("y"), sp.Symbol("z")
    T   = (1 - sp.cos(2*sp.pi*x))*(1 - sp.cos(2*sp.pi*y))*sp.sin(sp.pi*z)*0.1
    lambda_function = np.vectorize(sp.lambdify((x, y, z), T, "numpy"))
    x, y, z = np.mgrid[0:1:40*1j, 0:1:40*1j, 0:1:40*1j]
    T = lambda_function(x,y,z)
    return T
```

The problem between the sympy version and a pure numpy version is the speed i.e.

```
In [3]: timeit test.numpy_function()  
100 loops, best of 3: 11.9 ms per loop
```

vs.

```
In [4]: timeit test.sympy_function()
1 loops, best of 3: 634 ms per loop
```

So is there any way to get closer to the speed of the numpy version ? 
I think np.vectorize is pretty slow but somehow some part of my code does not work without it. Thank you for any suggestions.

**EDIT**:
So I found the reason why the vectorize function is necessary, i.e:

```
In [35]: y = np.arange(10)

In [36]: f = sp.lambdify(x,sin(x),"numpy")

In [37]: f(y)
Out[37]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.84147098,  0.90929743,  0.14112001, -0.7568025 ,
       -0.95892427, -0.2794155 ,  0.6569866 ,  0.98935825,  0.41211849])
```

this seems to work fine however:

```
In [38]: y = np.arange(10)

In [39]: f = sp.lambdify(x,1,"numpy")

In [40]: f(y)
Out[40]: 1
```

So for simple expression like `1`  this function doesn't return an array.
Is there a way to fix this and isn't this some kind of bug or at least inconsistent design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lambdify` returns a single value for constants because no numpy functions are involved. This is because of the way `lambdify` works (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25514007/161801).

But this is typically not a problem because a constant will automatically broadcast to the correct shape in any operation that you use it in with an array. On the other hand, if you explicitly worked with an array of the same constant, it would be much less efficient because you would compute the same operations multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My problem is that I have  something like  self.T = T(x,y,z) so in this case broadcasting doesn't work. What would be  the best way to do this ?

Comment: It looks like `numpy.array` is a no-op when called with an array, so you can use `np.array(T(x, y, z))` to ensure that the result is always an array.

Comment: Although I still don't understand why your use-case doesn't work with broadcasting.

Comment: @asmeurer I don't understand why even with something like: `f = lambdify(x, np.ones_like(x)*cte, 'numpy')` it returns the scalar `cte` no mather what `x` is... should I open an issue about it?

Comment: The second argument to lambdify must be a symbolic expression. `np.ones_like(Symbol('x'))` returns `array(1)`, so that's the same as `lambdify(x, array(1)*cte, 'numpy')`. Remember that only SymPy functions remain "unevaluated".

Comment: @asmeurer: So I still have a different shape or not? Lets say self.T.shape is (10, 10, 10). So after the assignment The shape of T should be (1,). Is there maybe some build in numpy function for this operation? I mean I could do s.th. like `self.T = np.zeros_like(self.T) + T(x,y,z)` but this is ugly in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Using `np.vectorize()` in this case is like looping over the first dimension of `x`, `y` and `z`, and that's why it becomes slower. You don't need `np.vectorize()` **IF** you tell `lambdify()`to use NumPy's functions, which is exactly what you are doing. Then, using:

```
def sympy_function():
    x, y, z = sp.Symbol("x"), sp.Symbol("y"), sp.Symbol("z")
    T   = (1 - sp.cos(2*sp.pi*x))*(1 - sp.cos(2*sp.pi*y))*sp.sin(sp.pi*z)*0.1
    lambda_function = sp.lambdify((x, y, z), T, "numpy")
    x, y, z = np.mgrid[0:1:40*1j, 0:1:40*1j, 0:1:40*1j]
    T = lambda_function(x,y,z)
    return T
```

makes the performance comparable:

```
In [26]: np.allclose(numpy_function(), sympy_function())
Out[26]: True

In [27]: timeit numpy_function()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.08 ms per loop

In [28]: timeit sympy_function()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.52 ms per loop
```

Comment: @jrsm you are right... I tried even `f= lambdify(x, (cte*np.ones_like(x)))` and `lambdify` returns always the `cte` value... this is probably a bug, I will open an issue in their issues list... hope my answer helped you anyways...